# Можно ли заставить Visual Studio не заменять «“» и «”» на «"» при автоформатировании XAML-файлов?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Можно ли заставить Visual Studio не заменять «“» и «”» (нормальные кавычки) на «"» (кавычки в коде) при автоформатировании XAML-файлов? Не смог найти какой-либо опции для этого.

Так-то бо́льшая часть строк в отдельном файле, но переношу я их туда не сразу — (хочу сперва убедиться, что получилось удобно и не придётся переделывать, чтобы не добавлять переводчикам лишней работы).

Comment: Хм, у Visual Studio есть же поиск-и-замена, почему бы не воспользоваться ей? Там даже можно указать поиск во всех файлах с нужным расширением. По-моему, как раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @VladD, прошу прощения, пока искал, как получше сформулировать вопрос, упустил «не». ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯